# How can I create an Encoder of type List[Row] in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use `flatMapGroupWithState` function on Spark DataFrame to have custom aggregations.

In the lambda of `flatMapGroupState`, I am trying to save List of `Row: GroupState[List[Row]]`.
Above mentioned code, is getting `Runtime Exception` by complaining about

> No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row.

But for `outputEncoder` it is working.

The question is: How can I create an encoder of type: `List[Row]` in spark?

```
val outputEncoder = RowEncoder(stateSchema)
val stateEncoder: Encoder[List[Row]] = ExpressionEncoder()

df.flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Update(), timeoutConf = GroupStateTimeout.EventTimeTimeout())(func = aggregationOperations)(stateEncoder, outputEncoder)
~
~
~

private def aggregationOperations(key: String, values: Iterator[Row], state: GroupState[List[Row]]): Iterator[Row] = {
~
~
~
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RowEncoder for

StructType(List(StructField("state", ArrayType(stateSchema))))